# E-mailing a link gets terminated at a double quote in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an application that sends an e-mail with several information. Among the information is a link to the location of the user to Google Maps. A sample of the link would be:

http://www.google.com.ph/maps/place/14°39'3.8952"N121°2'57.4116"E/@14.651082,121.049281,17z

The code looks like this:

```
"Google Maps Link: http://www.google.com.ph/maps/place/" +
        degToDMS(location.getLatitude()) + "\"N" +
        degToDMS(location.getLongitude()) + "\"E/@" +
        location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + ",17z");
```

I converted the degrees longitude and latitude to DMS using a formula I found online and it seemed to be returning good data. However, when I go check the email, the link looks like:

http://www.google.com.ph/maps/place/14°39'3.8952"N121°2'57.4116"E/@14.651082,121.049281,17z

and the hyperlink ends at the first double quote (") right before the N. This is actually a bit irritating and troubling because it doesn't link the entire link properly and it is cut.

How can I escape a double quote in a link? Or is there a better way to link to Google Maps?

Comment: Use java.net.URLEncoder

Comment: Try `\\\"` instead of `\"`

Comment: Will look into both solutions hold n.

Comment: @rotwang, Using `\\\"` instead of `\"` didn't work. @for3st, the url encoder works. Will answer my question now.

Comment: OK, it was a trial. I also thought of using `&quot;` in place of `\"`. Or `\u0022`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `URLEncode`, thanks to for3st for the lead, as such:

```
    final String urlRaw = degToDMS(location.getLatitude()) + "\"N" +
            degToDMS(location.getLongitude()) + "\"E/@" +
            location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + ",17z";


    String encodedURL = "";
    try {
        encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(urlRaw, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where `urlRaw` is the "problematic' part of your url (where characters don't get escaped properly or something). You **DON'T** put in the `http://....` because it will appear as such `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ph` and yeah you don't want that.

Hence, I only escaped the latter part of my url, the one that starts with the DMS coordinates.

Once I have my `encodedURL` variable, I simply concat it to the rest of the starting URL as such:

```
String link = "Google Maps Link: http://www.google.com.ph/maps/place/" + encodedURL;
```

and not it works.